Automate removing segments of a video using ffmpeg-python
I'm very new to ffmpeg and unable to wrap my head around the concepts entirely. My goal for this little script I've been working on all day is to:
Step 1: Read a list of timestamps from a text file like so:
00:00 - 00:14
00:30 - 00:45
So that works: for me:
def read_timestamps(file_path):
    timestamps = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            match = re.match(r'(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) - (\d{1,2}):(\d{2})', line.strip())
            if match:
                start = int(match.group(1)) * 60 + int(match.group(2))  # minutes:seconds -> total seconds
                end = int(match.group(3)) * 60 + int(match.group(4))    # minutes:seconds -> total seconds

                timestamps.append((start, end))
    return timestamps

Parsed timestamps: [(0, 14), (30, 45)] --------> CORRECT!
Step 2: Remove or Cut-out those parts from the original video file "input.mkv"
Rather, virtually "remember" the segments that are important leaving out the cut-out parts.
# Function to split the video based on the timestamps (no intermediate files)
def split_video(input_file, timestamps):
    segments = []
    
    # Assuming the input file is a long video, and we are removing the timestamp ranges
    video_duration = ffmpeg.probe(input_file, v="error", select_streams="v:0", show_entries="format=duration")["format"]["duration"]
    video_duration = float(video_duration)

    # Now we split the video based on the timestamp ranges
    prev_end = 0
    for start, end in timestamps:
        if start < end:
            # The part we want to keep is from prev_end to the start of the timestamp
            if prev_end < start:
                segments.append((prev_end, start))  # Add the segment before the removal range
            prev_end = end  # After the removal range, the video continues from 'end'
        else:
            print(f"Invalid timestamp range: {start} to {end}. Skipping this range.")
    
    # After processing all timestamps, add the remaining part from prev_end to the end of the video
    if prev_end < video_duration:
        segments.append((prev_end, video_duration))  # Last segment to the end of the video

    return segments


So for the above input, I correctly get the segments:
Segments: [(14, 30), (45, 2379.784)] -------------> CORRECT! (yes, input video is 39+ mins long)
Step 3: From the rest of the video clips that remain, I wanted to concatenate them all into a single "output.mp4", while ensuring that:
a. the concatenated video tracks transition with a cross-dissolve (or xfade in ffmpeg?)
b. the concatenated audio tracks transition with a cross-fade (or afade in ffmpeg?)
I was trying to see if hardcoded values worked because none of my loops were working and I was shooting in the dark. Atleast if I can get the hardcoded version to work, I can reverse-engineer a loop for it:

def concatenate_with_crossfade(input_file, segments, output_file):
    # Video inputs for two segments (start, end)
    input_video_1 = ffmpeg.input(input_file, ss=14, to=30)  # Segment 1 video
    input_audio_1 = ffmpeg.input(input_file, ss=14, to=30)  # Segment 1 audio

    input_video_2 = ffmpeg.input(input_file, ss=45, to=1000)  # Segment 2 video
    input_audio_2 = ffmpeg.input(input_file, ss=45, to=1000)  # Segment 2 audio


    filter_complex_str = (
        "[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=4[v1];"  # Crossfade between video
        "[0:a]afade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=30[a1];"         # Fade-out for first audio
        "[1:a]afade=type=in:duration=1:start_time=0[a2];"            # Fade-in for second audio
        "[v1][a1][a2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]"                 # Concatenate the results
    )

    # Pass the filter_complex to the ffmpeg command
    ffmpeg.output(input_video_1, input_video_2, input_audio_1, input_audio_2, output_file,
                vcodec="libx264", acodec="aac", audio_bitrate="192k", 
                filter_complex=filter_complex_str, shortest=None).run()

# Main script
def main():
    input_file = 'input.mkv'
    timestamps_file = 'timestamps.txt'
    output_file = 'output.mp4'

    # Step 1: Read the timestamps
    timestamps = read_timestamps(timestamps_file)
    print(f"Parsed timestamps: {timestamps}")

    # Step 2: Split the video into segments based on the timestamps
    segments = split_video(input_file, timestamps)
    print(f"Segments to keep: {segments}")

    # Step 3: Concatenate with crossfade
    concatenate_with_crossfade(input_file, segments, output_file)

    print(f"Output saved to {output_file}")

# Run the script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Problems:
Throughout Step 3, all my attemps have been getting issues like:
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000013bf9904e80] More input link labels specified for filter 'concat' than it has inputs: 3 > 2
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000013bf9904e80] Error linking filters
Failed to set value '[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=4[v1];[0:a]afade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=30[a1];[1:a]afade=type=in:duration=1:start_time=0[a2];[v1][a1][a2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]' for option 'filter_complex': Invalid argument
Error parsing global options: Invalid argument

OR
[fc#0 @ 000001c1203d4ac0] Filter xfade:default has an unconnected output
Error binding filtergraph inputs/outputs: Invalid argument

OR
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000023dd82e4e80] More input link labels specified for filter 'concat' than it has inputs: 3 > 2
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000023dd82e4e80] Error linking filters
Failed to set value '[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=4[v1];[0:a]afade=type=out:duration=1:start_time=30[a1];[1:a]afade=type=in:duration=1:start_time=0[a2];[v1][a1][a2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]' for option 'filter_complex': Invalid argument
Error parsing global options: Invalid argument

OR
[aist#0:1/aac @ 000001b549c7bd00] Cannot decode a disabled input stream
[fc#0 @ 000001b549c748c0] Error binding an input stream to complex filtergraph input afade:default.
Error binding filtergraph inputs/outputs: Invalid argument

And I'm at a loss. Can anyone spot a mistake in the hardcoded filtergraph in the string filter_complex_str in step 3 - because I'm 90% sure I am messing that up in some way? I would really appreciate your help on the matter! Thank you!

try to replace afade concat with acrossfade → [0:v][1:v]xfade=fade:duration=1:offset=5[v1]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=1[a1]

Hello, like I said I am new to ffmpeg so I don't understand a lot of things here. Do you mean like this:
filter_complex_str = (         "[0:v][1:v]   xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=4[v1];" # Crossfade between video         "[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=1[a1];" # Crossfade for audio                "[v1][a1]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" # Concatenate the results          )
This is what I get:
[fc#0 @ 000002480ed74880] Filter concat has an unconnected output Error binding filtergraph inputs/outputs: Invalid argument

no, try → filter_complex_str = ( "[0:v][1:v]xfade=fade:duration=1:offset=4[outv]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=1[outa]" )

Same output unfortunately! [fc#0 @ 000001856cf04e00] Filter xfade:default has an unconnected output Error binding filtergraph inputs/outputs: Invalid argument

tested some part of your code, it works by this way for me → xf12 = ffmpeg.filter((input_video_1, input_video_2), 'xfade', transition="fade", duration=1, offset=4) af12 = ffmpeg.filter((input_audio_1, input_audio_2), 'acrossfade', duration=1) fine = ffmpeg.output(xf12, af12, output_file, vcodec="h264_nvenc", acodec="aac", audio_bitrate="192k") fine.run()

Hello, though the code runs fine, the output seems corrupted and much smaller than the original file, so I'm guessing it didn't do the trick!

duration of your 1st cut is 16, so change offset to 15. tested → def concatenate_with_crossfade(input_file, segments, output_file):     in_1 = ffmpeg.input(input_file, ss=5.5, to=10.5)     in_2 = ffmpeg.input(input_file, ss=25, to=30)     xf12 = ffmpeg.filter((in_1, in_2), 'xfade', transition="fade", duration=1, offset=4)     af12 = ffmpeg.filter((in_1, in_2), 'acrossfade', duration=1)     ffmpeg.output(xf12, af12, output_file, vcodec="h264_nvenc", acodec="aac", audio_bitrate="192k").run()

The file still does not run on Windows Media Player. And it's even smaller now...? Am I supposed to use a different "codec" for it to work?

increase offset=4 to your value → offset=15. change codec to vcodec="h264" or vcodec="libx264" → in_1 = ffmpeg.input(input_file, ss=14, to=30)     in_2 = ffmpeg.input(input_file, ss=45, to=47)     xf12 = ffmpeg.filter((in_1, in_2), 'xfade', transition="fade", duration=1, offset=15)     af12 = ffmpeg.filter((in_1, in_2), 'acrossfade', duration=1)     fine = ffmpeg.output(xf12, af12, output_file, vcodec="h264", acodec="aac", audio_bitrate="192k")     args = fine.get_args()     print(f'---------> {args}')     fine.run() not tested
